# How to add the function with dataType Seq[row] => Seq[row] to dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

example

```
def exampleFun : Seq[Row] => Seq[Row]{
some code
}
```

How should I add this in dataframe or there is a way to convert this to datatype Dataframe => DataFrame

Comment: post full code and also share what you are trying to do

Comment: Mayabe you want: `df.map(exampleFun)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert your function from `Seq[Row] => Seq[Row]` to `DataFrame => DataFrame` you can do it via `dataFrame.flatMap`, for example:

```
val func: DataFrame => DataFrame = df => df.flatMap(row => exampleFun(Seq(row)))
```

But make sure that you have specified `Encoder[Row]` implicitly, otherwise it won't compile